# Who said Moshe is missing from the Haggadah to emphasize HaShem?

Tags: sources-mekorot, passover-seder-hagada, moshe-rabbeinu, vilna-gaon

Where is the source of the Vilna Gaon/the Gra or any commentator explaining that Moshe is left out of the haggadah (besides [the one time](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pesach_Haggadah%2C_Magid%2C_The_Ten_Plagues.18?ven=Sefaria_Edition&vhe=Pesach_Haggadah&lang=en) he is mentioned) in order to show that it was Hashem who did the miracle and not Moshe?

Comment: He's not left out. [He is explicitly mentioned](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesach_Haggadah,_Magid,_The_Ten_Plagues.18).

Comment: Please clarify if Harel's edit matches your intent

Comment: I only heard it was from the Gra.  There are many other reasons why Moses has been left out.  The explanation I like the best is the recognition that children, for whom the Haggadah was established, have difficulty understanding God, but can easily understand a great leader like Moses.  In order to make them know and appreciate God, we must de-emphasize Moses.  I don't remember the source.

Comment: @Dina -- Is your question just the one in the title or the more focused one in your message?

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi my q is the more focused one in the message

Comment: See: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37319/27180

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message from the Gra can be found on his explanation of the Haggadah [here](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/623837/p/71/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/6hikocamgUkqUHUhKYuVeGvSufJxiLAfd8hZCfHftjvk/start/0/end/64/c).

[image]

My translation reads as follows:

> And the revelation that was revealed; this is His (Hashem's) honour that was revealed to all by Moshe Rabbeinu who did not take from it the honour for himself G-d forbid, rather the opposite he lowered himself in all matters and revealed to all that it was Hashem alone (Who acted as He did) for Israel, and also he too (Moshe), is one of his servants and this is in his own right. **And therefore in all the story of the Exodus of Egypt we don't make a point of remembering Moshe G-d forbid, since it is forbidden for us to join anything in his honour and himself, and the praise is not dependent on Moshe but rather Hashem alone**, and anyone who joins / connects the name of Heaven and another entity is uprooted from the world ([Succah 45b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.45b.7?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). Therefore, it writes "And they believed in Hashem and in Moshe His servant", this means (we're speaking) not about the greatness of Moshe, rather the opposite, to the faith will ask and answer Moshe that believed that Hashem did all this, and Moshe is only his servant like all creations in the world that are obligated to do His will. Therefore then Moshe and the Israelites sang all together since they were equal in the miracle...